# Play framework template didn't syncronized and didn't recognized by eclipse

Tags: eclipse, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have been running simple hello world app in Play Framework (Java). However, template doesn't recognize my template arguments.

Template(view):

```
@(userName: String)

@main("Welcome!"){
    <h1>Welcome @userName</h1>
}
```

Controller:

[image]

You can see the error line. Also I have compile error which is below :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start from the compilation error because this is the root of of your problems.

In the 3rd line of your `main.scala.html`:

```
@main("Welcome!"){
```

you're trying to call you `main.scala.html` which is incorrect. Your `main.scala.html` is trying to call itself recurrently which ends up with the compilation error. Since the template can not be compiled your IDE still shows a previous valid compiled template which takes two parameters. I'm assuming you changed it from the standard Play Java template which looks as follows:

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)
```

Changing your main template as shown below should solve your problem.

```
@(userName: String)

<h1>Welcome @userName</h1>
```

Comment: Thank your answer. However, when I compile it in terminal, IDE will see my templates codes. How can I syncronize IDE. Because I compiled after that I exit in Eclipse, then when I start again, it is seen there. It is a problem I guess.

Comment: I don't work with Eclipse on an everyday basis but I believe it is related with the way how templates work. In the development mode templates are compiled after running an application. Eclipse prompts probably work on compiled version of templates which means that before running an application IDE always shows declaration of previously compiled templates. In IntelliJ which I use they are synchronized well.

Comment: Thanks Daniel I guess I will use IntelliJ.